# Use OpenCart as a backend service

Tags: opencart

I have a client that wants to use OpenCart. But we don't want to use it for the vast majority of things (front end, etc). I know it has templating options, but we're not happy with them.

Is it possible to use OpenCart as a backend service (via some API) and have our own front end service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible to only use the admin portion. There's no "API" as such for the front end, you would need to create your own, or piggyback off the framework

Comment: As @JayGilford mentioned, it's very easy to create and maintain estores with openCart, if you want to perform simple tasks, such as creating categories and adding products. However, I was working on a project to convert orders into products using php, and that proved much more difficult, well, at least for me. I couldn't find it, and now looking for an alternative.